# get all values in an ip range

Tags: php, ip, range

Pls help,

I have a form which contains two fields to enter ip range say

```
      |iprange1| and  |iprange2|
```

What I want to print all ip between iprange1 and iprange2. Lets say I want to print ip's between

```
    192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.10
```

how to do this?

Comment: [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) & [`long2ip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php); demo : http://codepad.org/3QDQ2OVK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo : http://codepad.org/3QDQ2OVK.

```
$ip1 = '192.168.1.2';
$ip2 = '192.168.1.10';

for ($ip = ip2long($ip1); $ip<=ip2long($ip2); $ip++)
{
    echo long2ip($ip) . "\n";
}
```

Thanks to NullUserException.